# Checking equality of strings by writing strings as a list

Tags: haskell

> Exercise 4 . Write a function that takes a string and returns True if the string
> is "hello" and False otherwise. This can be done by specifying each
> element of the string in the list pattern (e.g. ’h’:’i’:[]). ,page-19, Discrete Mathematics Using a computer, Donell , Hall & Rex

The previous exercise to this was a simpler question, which went as follows:

> Ex 3. Write a function that takes a character and returns True if the
> character is ’a’ and False otherwise.

This I solved with the code:

```hs
f :: Char -> Bool
f 'a' = True
f x   = False
```

I am supposing for this problem, it should be similar with:

```hs
f :: [Char] -> Bool
f 'hello' = True
f x = False
```

Now, the above code doesn't work when I load it. I am guessing we can't just directly evaluate functions on strings, why?

Comment: For your future ref, "doesn't work" is unhelpful for anybody trying to answer this. GHC is your friend: it produces error messages that help you (or someone here) to figure it out. I get ` Parse error in pattern: 'hello'` -- which tells `'hello'` is using the wrong syntax. This corresponds to the type signature `Char -> ...` vs `[Char] -> ...`.

Answer (score 4):

`'hello'` makes no sense, `'x'` is a character, a `Char`, so it can not contain multiple characters. You can write it as `"hello"`, `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, or `'h' : 'e' : 'l' : 'l' : 'o' : []`, which are all the same expression so:

```
f :: [Char] -> Bool
f "hello" = True
f x = False

f :: [Char] -> Bool
f ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] = True
f x = False

f :: [Char] -> Bool
f ('h' : 'e' : 'l' : 'l' : 'o' : []) = True
f x = False


f :: [Char] -> Bool
f ((:) 'h' ((:) 'e' ((:) 'l' ((:) 'l' ((:) 'o' []))))) = True
f x = False
```

the list is not really exhaustive, since we can combine ways to define lists, for example as `(:) 'h' ('e' : [ 'l', 'l', 'o'])`.

Answer (score 0):

(@willM_'s answer isn't wrong, but I think it's over-complicating the matter.)

- `'a'` is a `Char`acter constant. The rule is they must contain a single character.
- `'hello'` contains more than one character. It's not a character constant, nor a list of characters; it's just plain illegal syntax.
- The way to write a list-of-characters constant (aka `String`) is double quotes: `"hello"`.
- Some languages do support using the same quotes for either `Char` or `String`. But those are different types in Haskell, and Haskell is very particular about types: it would be ambiguous whether `'a'` is a `Char` constant or a length-1 `String`.
- (Complication: between `' '` you can put escape sequences or ASCII codes to get a single `Char`. For example `'\''` is how to get the constant for single-quote; `'\127'` gets `DEL`.)

Your signature for `f :: [Char] -> Bool` says `f` is to expect a `String` argument. So

```
f 'h' = ...
```

Would be valid syntax; but is ill-typed; so you'd get an error wrt the typing as opposed to a syntax error.